# Flutter -How To Expand a Column

Tags: flutter

I have a Column:  `child: Column( children: [ Container( height: 200, width: 300, color: Colors.red, ), Align( alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: Text("This Product is Built By Imtiaz")), ], ),`
I want to Expand Column to print Text At Bottom Of Screen

Comment: You Should Expand your Text Widget

Comment: Why are you answering yourself?
Maybe you could use `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `Spacer()` between your `Text` widget and your `Container` widget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Text("This Product is Built By Imtiaz"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```